# Code duplication in buzzfizz program including negative numbers

Tags: c

Hello i want to avoid code duplication in my program (buzzfizz including negative numbers)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int myseries(int n) {
  int i, cpt = 0;
  if (n < 0) {
    for (i = 0; i >= n; i--) {
      // if the number is multiple of both three and five
      if (i % 15 == 0) {
        printf("lancelot\n");
      }
      // if the number is multiple of 3
      else if(i % 3 == 0) {
        printf("Fizz\n");
      }
      // if the number is multiple of 5
      else if(i % 5 == 0) {
        printf("Buzz\n");
        cpt++;
      }
      else {
        printf("%d\n", i);
      }
    }
    return cpt;
  }
  else {
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      // if the number is multiple of both three and five
      if (i % 15 == 0) {
        printf("lancelot\n");
      }
      // if the number is multiple of 3
      else if(i % 3 == 0) {
        printf("Fizz\n");
      }
      //if the number is multiple of 5
      else if(i % 5 == 0) {
        printf("Buzz\n");
        cpt++;
      }
      else {
        printf("%d\n",i);
      }
    }
    return cpt;
  }
}

//example

main() {
  printf("the number of buzz is : %d", myseries(-16));
}
```

Comment: Extract the common code to a function.

Comment: And please get rid of the unnecessary empty lines.

Comment: thank you , but if i don't want to add other functions..

Comment: Probably better asked on [codereview.se].

Comment: @HajarM out of curiosity why don't you want to add other functions?

Comment: @jayant the exercice says you have to write one function.

Comment: @HajarM ok then the answer below seems good

Answer (score 3):

You can use the absolute value of `n` (i.e. `abs(n)`) as `i`'s upper bound, and record `n`'s sign (i.e. `bool sgn = ( n > 0 ) ? 1 : 0;`) for output.